# Failed to generate gRPC service classes

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to follow along with this [tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/). I am stuck on trying to generate the .grpc files (service classes) but I was able to generate the message classes. When I run

```
protoc -I ../proto --grpc_out=. 
       --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=grpc_cpp_plugin ../proto/eample.proto
```

I get *"grpc_cpp_plugin: program not found"*. How can I generate the service classes? Im not sure about the correct command I have to run.

Answer (score 5):

The question is pretty old, but I hope my answer will help somebody. Giorgio Azzinnaro was right you need to install GRPC (in addition to protoc). On OSX you can do it with:

```
brew install grpc
```

For the other languages, commands are described [here](https://grpc.io/blog/installation/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to run this?

```
$ which grpc_cpp_plugin
```

If it finds a match, try to use the full path:

```
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_cpp_plugin`
```

If that isn't found, see if it is there in `/usr/local/bin` (it might just not be in the path), and if you find it there again use the full path in the `--plugin` directive.

If all this fails I suppose it might be that gRPC was not installed correctly...